# how to remove this error (android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xffffffff)

Tags: java, android, string, sqlite, android-resources

I'm building an Android app that contain SQLite DB and I was having a problem with translating SQLite saved data then I find a solution which is a method to get resource id of strings, and it worked just fine, the app was working fine then suddenly this error showed I don't know why,  please help

The method, I used to get resource for string:

```
     public static int getResId(String resName, Class<?> c) {

        try {
            Field idField = c.getDeclaredField(resName);
            return idField.getInt(idField);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

The code in the adapter

```
    textViewname.setText(context.getString(R.string.product_Name)+" " + repo.getName());
    textViewquantity.setText(context.getString(R.string.last_added_qty)+" " + repo.getQuantity() + " " + context.getResources().getString(mdatabase.getResId(repo.getItemsType(),R.string.class)));
    textViewdate.setText(context.getString(R.string.entry_date)+" " + repo.getDate()+ " /"+context.getResources().getString(mdatabase.getResId(repo.getInOrOut(),R.string.class)));
    textViewTotal.setText(context.getString(R.string.total_qty)+" " + repo.getTotal() + " " + context.getResources().getString(mdatabase.getResId(repo.getItemsType(),R.string.class)));
    textviewlastUpdated.setText(context.getString(R.string.last_updated_date)+" " + repo.getUpdateDate() +" /"+context.getResources().getString(mdatabase.getResId(repo.getInOrOut(),R.string.class)));
    textViewid.setText(context.getString(R.string.id)+" " + repo.getId());
    textViewOutputqty.setText(context.getString(R.string.last_out_qty)+" " + repo.getOutputqty() + " " + context.getResources().getString(mdatabase.getResId(repo.getItemsType(),R.string.class)));
    textViewpriceofsingleitem.setText(context.getString(R.string.retail_price)+" " + repo.getPrice() + " " + context.getResources().getString(mdatabase.getResId(repo.getCurrency(),R.string.class)));
    textViewpriceofMultipleitem.setText(context.getString(R.string.wholesale_price)+" " + repo.getPriceofmultipleInput() + " " + context.getResources().getString(mdatabase.getResId(repo.getCurrency(),R.string.class)));
    textViewProfitSIngle.setText(context.getString(R.string.retail_profit)+" " + repo.getProfitSingle() + " " + context.getResources().getString(mdatabase.getResId(repo.getCurrency(),R.string.class)));
    textViewProfitMultiple.setText(context.getString(R.string.wholesale_profit)+" " + repo.getProfitMultiple() + " " + context.getResources().getString(mdatabase.getResId(repo.getCurrency(),R.string.class)));
    textViewPurchasingPrice.setText(context.getString(R.string.purchasing_price)+" " + repo.getPurchasingPricePeranItem() + " " + context.getResources().getString(mdatabase.getResId(repo.getCurrency(),R.string.class)));
    textViewTotalPurchasingPrice.setText(context.getString(R.string.total_purchase_price)+" " + repo.getTotalPurchasingPrice() + " " + context.getResources().getString(mdatabase.getResId(repo.getCurrency(),R.string.class)));
    textViewTotalProfitSingle.setText(context.getString(R.string.total_retail_profit)+" " + repo.getTotalProfitperSingle() + " " + context.getResources().getString(mdatabase.getResId(repo.getCurrency(),R.string.class)));
    textViewTotalProfitMultiple.setText(context.getString(R.string.total_wholesale_profit)+" "+ repo.getTotalProfitPerMultiple() + " " + context.getResources().getString(mdatabase.getResId(repo.getCurrency(),R.string.class)));
    textViewitemsIBox.setText(context.getString(R.string.num_unitsInBox)+" "+ repo.getItemsInBox());
    textViewSinglePriceOfiteminBox.setText(context.getString(R.string.retail_price_perUnit)+ " " + repo.getSinglePriceofItemInBox()+" " +context.getResources().getString(mdatabase.getResId(repo.getCurrency(),R.string.class)));
    textViewMultipriceOfItemInBox.setText(context.getString(R.string.wholesale_price_perUnit)+" "+repo.getMultiplePriceofitemInBox()+" "+context.getResources().getString(mdatabase.getResId(repo.getCurrency(),R.string.class)));
    textViewtotalItemsInBoexs.setText(context.getString(R.string.total_units)+" "+ repo.getTotalitemsInboxes() +" "+ context.getResources().getString(R.string.Pieces));
```

Comment: `0xffffffff` is `-1` in decimal, so something's likely throwing in the `try` block in your `getResId()` method, and you should have a look in your logs for that stack trace you're printing there. Furthermore, you should be passing `null` in the `idField.getInt()` call, not `idField` itself; i.e., `return idField.getInt(null);`.

Comment: it didnt work I'm surprised because it worked at first I dont know what happened !! I cleaned the project and reinstalled the app again it worked then I got the error back again

Comment: And what did you find in your logs? No resource ID will have a value of `-1`, so something's throwing in that `try` block, if this is indeed where the Exception is happening.

Comment: One way to debug this kind of problem is to add these `setText` statements 1 by 1 - I guess one of your values from DB is returning null and therefore `c.getDeclaredField(null)` returns something bad. So check your db if all the columns have legit values in that.

Comment: I found out what is causing this error, I was trying to translate the saved data in sqlite if the user change the device language to arabic for example, when i changed the device language to arabic It didnt work because the method is searching for strings is not existed u see the string  resource name by default is in english but when I insert it in arabic the method wont work with it , I didnt solve this problem yet.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens because you are trying to get resource that does not exist. It is because you store memory address which allocate to your string resource and possible it will change next time. I do not know what is your scenario but why you store it already in your strings it will never lost. I can help you to build another logic only when you tell what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Ive tried this: public static int getStringIdentifier(Context context, String name) {
    return context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "string", context.getPackageName());
}     but its returning 0

Comment: I found out what is causing this error, I was trying translate the saved data in sqlite if the user change the device language to arabic for example, I searched a lot for a solution then I've tried this method at first i thought it worked but , then when i changed the device language to arabic It didnt work because the method is searching for strings is not existed u see the string resource name by default is in english but when I insert it in arabic the method wont work with it!! any help for that ?